# Property 'listName' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I get theProperty 'listName' does not exist on type '{}' when I run the following code inside my details page. It seems something trivial, but I spent the entire afternoon not able to understand what is going wrong here.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ListDetailsService} from '../../providers/list-details-service';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-item-details',
  templateUrl: 'item-details.html'
})
export class ItemDetailsPage {
  selectedItem: any;
  detailsItems : Array<{title: string, note: string, id: string}>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public listDetailsService : ListDetailsService) {
    // If we navigated to this page, we will have an item available as a nav param
    this.selectedItem = navParams.get('item');

    this.detailsItems = [];
    this.listDetailsService.load(this.selectedItem.id).then(myListItems => {
      console.log(myListItems);
      console.log(myListItems.listName);


    }).catch(function(e){
      console.log(e);
    })
  }
}
```

When I run console.log(myListItems), I get the following data.

```
{
items: 
   [ { _id: 58bbf7fd463667f51d7804f6,
       votes: '10',
       item: 'Apple Iphone' },
     { _id: 58bbf7fd463667f51d7804f5,
       votes: '2',
       item: 'Google Phone' },
     { _id: 58bbf7fd463667f51d7804f4,
       votes: '2',
       item: 'Samsung Phone' },
     { _id: 58bbf7fd463667f51d7804f3, votes: '6', item: 'LG Phone' } ],
  __v: 0,
  listName: 'Best Phones',
  _id: 58bbf7fd463667f51d7804f2 }
```

However, when I run

```
console.log(myListItems.listName);
```

I get

```
Property 'listName' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Even though the property is present in the object myListNames

I am sure I am missing something  trivial here. But I spend the entire afternoon, not knowing the answer.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a TypeScript compiler error, and you should probably change the return type of your `listDetailsService.load` function to either `any` or an interface you define which matches the object of your list.

```
export class ListDetailsService {

  //...
  load(): any {
      //...
  }  

}
```

Comment: Thank you,that worked! I wasn't thinking typescript at all.